# problem with template inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

I'm trying to understand whay i get an error on this code:
(the error is under g++ unix compiler. VS is compiling OK)

```
template<class T> class A {
public:
    T t;
public:
    A(const T& t1) : t(t1) {}
    virtual void Print() const { cout<<*this<<endl;}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A<T>& a) {
            out<<"I'm "<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
            out<<"I hold "<<typeid(a.t).name()<<endl;
            out<<"The inner value is: "<<a.t<<endl;
            return out;
    }
};

template<class T> class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(const T& t1) : A<T>(t1) {}
    const T& get() const { return t; }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a(9);
    a.Print();
    B<A<int> > b(a); 
    b.Print();
    (b.get()).Print();  
    return 0;
}
```

This code is giving the following error:

main.cpp: In member function 'const T& B::get() const':
main.cpp:23: error: 't' was not declared in this scope

It did compiled when i changed the code of B to this:

```
template<class T> class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(const T& t1) : A<T>(t1) {}
    const T& get() const { return A<T>::t; }
};
```

I just cant understand what is the problem with the first code...
It doesn't make sense that i really need to write "A::" every time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `this->t` to access the base class template member.

In `B::get()`, the name `t` is not dependent on the template parameter `T`, so it is not a dependent name.  Base class `A<T>` is obviously dependent on the template parameter `T` and is thus a dependent base class.  Nondependent names are not looked up in dependent base classes.  [A detailed description of why this is the case can be found in the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19).

Comment: The FAQ is wrong on the reason why "this->" works. Compare it with the Standard (emphasize by me). FAQ: "Since this is always implicitly dependent in a template, this->f *is dependent and the lookup is therefore deferred* until the template is actually instantiated, *at which point all base classes are considered* ", Standard: "... the base class scope *is not examined* during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member *or during an instantiation* of the class template or member.". The FAQ says it's found because it's dependent, but that's wrong.

Comment: GCC also implements this wrong interpretation, and as a result [has bug reports open](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43282)