# GCC template issues

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with template inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982660/problem-with-template-inheritance)

This code doesn't compile in GCC:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
public:
 int x;
};

template <typename B>
struct Middle : public B
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Sub : public Middle<Base<T> >
{
public:
 void F()
 {
  x=1; // error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
 }
};
```

If either `Base` or `Sub` weren't template classes, it wouldn't complain. VC handles it.

Why?

Comment: Duplicate of [problem with template inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982660/problem-with-template-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this->x = 1;` to tell the compiler that `x` is a (template-) dependent name. 
**Note**: What GCC does ot fine according to the standard, MSVC is just a bit more tolerant.